# How i can include new middleware class

Tags: python, django

Got myself middleware class. Try include that. But have errorn

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'fun.middleware.AuthMiddleware',
]
```

---

> File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in
>   import_module
>       **import**(name) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'fun.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error
>   importing module: 'No module named middleware'

How i can include that?

Comment: Just to check: you have `__init__.py` in your fun directory, which also contains middleware.py which in turn has something named AuthMiddleware?

Comment: Please tell us how you installed the middleware, and list everything you've done do enable it.

Comment: i just add new directroy middleware and file AuthMiddleware in my main application directory